# Sort row where date is today

Tags: mysql, date-format

I'm having a small issue where I try to select all the rows where the user birthday is today.

In my table, my data is something similar like this yyyy-mm-dd formated in a varchar.

My current request is :

```
SELECT * FROM rb_users WHERE user_birthday = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%m %d')
```

I know that the above will return nothing as I readed on the documentation. As I understand, I would need to do `DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d')` to make it work.

My question is : Is there anyway to ignore the year in this kind of strucutre or I should edit my field to **unixformat** like 1402012800?

As is it done right now, I will only get people when there birthdays are in 2015.

**Source #1 :** 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24076419/sql-query-to-check-birthday-is-today

Comment: DATE_FORMAT(user_birthday, '%m %d') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%m %d') ?

Answer (score 0):

Because you have indicated that the column user_birthday is a varchar, you can use string function as follows.  Also be sure to add the hyphen ("-") into your DATE_FORMAT:

```
SELECT * FROM rb_users WHERE RIGHT(user_birthday, 5) = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%m-%d')
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_right

Comment: This could be a solution too! Thx for sharing it with me